# How to cross compile my C code containing JNI?

Tags: java, c, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

Previously I asked a question related to calling java function at

[Calling Java functions from C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573173/calling-java-functions-from-c-language)

Somehow I did with that.
Now I am planning to cross compile that.

I am facing an issue.
Before cross compiling ( means compiling in the same pc for the same pc)
I used the commands

```
gcc -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include  -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -L /usr/bin/java -L /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server  MyC.c -ljvm ;
```

That created well.
But now I am trying to cross compile the same for my target `arm-none-eabi-`

My makefile

```
CROSS_COMPILE =arm-none-eabi-
JAVA_HOME =/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
test:
    javac -d ./ MyJava.java
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc -I $(JAVA_HOME)include \
            -I $(JAVA_HOME)include/linux \
            -L $(JAVA_HOME)jre/lib/amd64/server \
             MyC.c -ljvm
```

This returning error

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: I guess you need cross compiled libs to cross compile your app. Libs that you are linking are not compiled for the target architecture.

Comment: Yaa. Am I need to have target header files too? And target java, javac commands?

Comment: You need a SDK for your target.

Comment: If you have successfully installed the SDK do remember to export the PATH to the environment variable. Then that should work.

Comment: Your trying to link to the amd64 version and not the arm one. This is wrong: -L $(JAVA_HOME)jre/lib/amd64/server

Comment: Yaa. Its a bad Idea to cross compile with shared libraries. So I moved to java.